# String Comparison with Keys on XSLT 1.0 transform

Tags: xml, key, xslt-1.0, string-comparison

I'm currently working on an xslt using xslt 1.0 to look at a response from a webservice and tell me if there is a difference in value. Issue is the response is dynamic. I am having some issues with using keys/dont know if the way I'm using it is correct

In my example we are checking attendance in high school classes and need to know if there is a difference in the number of students who have attended in the last 5 days. The xml response we receive is below

```
<response>
    <school1>
        <class>
        <attendance><class>a</class><day>monday</day><count>20</count></attendance>
        <attendance><class>a</class><day>tuesday</day><count>20</count></attendance>
        <attendance><class>a</class><day>wednesday</day><count>20</count></attendance>
        <attendance><class>a</class><day>thursday</day><count>20</count></attendance>   
        <attendance><class>a</class><day>friday</day><count>20</count></attendance>
        <attendance><class>b</class><day>monday</day><count>20</count></attendance>
        <attendance><class>b</class><day>tuesday</day><count>20</count></attendance>
        <attendance><class>b</class><day>wednesday</day><count>12</count></attendance>
        <attendance><class>b</class><day>thursday</day><count>20</count></attendance> 
        <attendance><class>b</class><day>friday</day><count>20</count></attendance>
       <attendance><class>c</class><day>monday</day><count>22</count></attendance>
       <attendance><class>c</class><day>tuesday</day><count>23</count></attendance>
       <attendance><class>c</class><day>wednesday</day><count>12</count></attendance>
       <attendance><class>c</class><day>thursday</day><count>20</count></attendance>
       <attendance><class>c</class><day>friday</day><count>22</count></attendance>
        </class>
    </school1>
</response>
```

My xslt should step through each class and compare the count, if there is a difference in numbers it should write out a message to alert the person. The xslt I have is throwing compile errors so i'm not sure I am using keys(a new concept to me) correctly. The xslt I have for this is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="test" match="attendance[class='a']" use="count"/>
    <xsl:key name="test2" match="attendance[class='a'][last()]" use="count"/>
    <xsl:key name="test3" match="attendance[class='b']" use="count"/>
    <xsl:key name="test4" match="attendance[class='b'][last()]" use="count"/>
    <xsl:key name="test5" match="attendance[class='c']" use="count"/>
    <xsl:key name="test6" match="attendance[class='c'][last()]" use="count"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="/response/school1/class/attendance">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$test!=$test2">
                    <xsl:value-of select="Check class roll" />                
              </xsl:when>  
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Perfect Attendance" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:when test ="$test3!=$test4">
                    <xsl:value-of select="Check class roll" />                
                </xsl:when>  
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Perfect Attendance" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:when test ="$test5!=$test6">
                    <xsl:value-of select="Check class roll" />                
                </xsl:when>  
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Perfect Attendance" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I expect an output of

Perfect Attendance
Check class roll
Check class roll

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are a few things wrong here: you've omitted to declare the XSLT namespace for the `xsl:` prefix; you have an `xsl:choose` containing more than 1 `xsl:otherwise` statement, and you have declared that the stylesheet produces XML (with your `xsl:output` statement), though it actually produces just a sequence of text nodes. You have `xsl:value-of` statements whose `select` attributes are supposed to be XPath expressions to evaluate, but you have passed strings.

Comment: Then you are using keys incorrectly as well; you don't refer to keys as variables but as parameters to the `key` function <https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#function-key>, but actually I wouldn't recommend using keys for this problem, but rather grouping.

Comment: If you're getting compile errors, please tell us what they are. Diagnosing a problem always starts by looking at the symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to hardcode the class names into your stylesheet, then you could get the expected result quite simply using:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="attend-by-class" match="attendance" use="class" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="a" select="key('attend-by-class', 'a')" />
    <xsl:variable name="b" select="key('attend-by-class', 'b')" />
    <xsl:variable name="c" select="key('attend-by-class', 'c')" />
    <!-- output -->
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$a/count != $a/count">Check class roll</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>Perfect Attendance</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$b/count != $b/count">Check class roll</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>Perfect Attendance</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$c/count != $c/count">Check class roll</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>Perfect Attendance</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A smarter approach would eliminate both hard-coding and code repetition by utilizing the same key to perform [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) by class, before doing the comparison within each group.

Note also that a result of `"Perfect Attendance"`does **not** in fact signify perfect attendance. All we are testing here are fluctuations in attendance. If class `a` has 21 students, and exactly one student was absent on every one of the 5 days tested, then the result will be reported as `"Perfect Attendance"` nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

This solution may interest you.  Good luck!

```
<xsl:key name="class" match="attendance" use="class"/>

<xsl:template match="class">
  <!-- Get the first class of each group.  -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="attendance[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('class',class)[1])]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="attendance">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="key('class',class)/count != key('class',class)/count">
      <xsl:value-of select="'Check class roll'"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="'Perfect Attendance'"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is actually a classic of the kind of problem which is best solved with *grouping* rather than using keys. You want to process the `attendance` elements grouped by their `class`. and for each group, you want to see if there is any discrepancy between the `count` elements in the group.

**EDIT** I've made some changes to my original answer since obviously `for-each-group` is not avialable in XSLT 1 - sorry!

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="attendances" select="/response/school1/class/attendance"/>
        <attendances>
            <xsl:for-each select="$attendances[not(class=preceding-sibling::attendance/class)]">
                <xsl:variable name="current-class" select="class"/>
                <xsl:variable name="current-class-attendances" select="$attendances[class=$current-class]"/>
                <result class="{class}">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$current-class-attendances/count != $current-class-attendances/count">
                            <xsl:text>Check class roll</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:text>Perfect Attendance</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </result>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </attendances>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have changed the template which matches `/` so that it creates a root element (which I called `attendances`). If your stylesheet doesn't produce a single root element then the output will not be well-formed XML. If you actually do want to produce plain text, then you should change your `xsl:output/@method` to `text`. I also wrapped the text messages with `result` and gave them a `class` attribute so you could see which result belongs to which class.

The `for-each` statement selects every attendance which is the first to have a particular class (i.e. it has no preceding-siblings which have the same class). I have a `current-class-attendances` variable which filters the full list of attendances down to just the ones for the current class. The `xsl:when` statement checks to see if there are any differences in the `count` among those `attendance` elements.

The expression `$current-class-attendances/count != $current-class-attendances/count` may seem a little cryptic, but it's actually straightforward. In XPath, this is called a "general comparison" https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-general-comparisons. If you compare two nodesets using an operator like `!=` (or `=`, `<`, etc) then the expression will evaluate to true *if* the comparison is true for at least one of the nodes from the left-hand nodeset and one from the right-hand nodeset. So `$some-nodes != $some-nodes` means "is there any node in the $some-nodes nodeset which is not equal to another node in the $some-nodes nodeset?"

Result:

```xml
<attendance>
   <result class="a">Perfect Attendance</result>
   <result class="b">Check class roll</result>
   <result class="c">Check class roll</result>
</attendance>
```

Can I suggest though that you really need to do some systematic study of the basics of XSLT, e.g. working your way through a book about it?

EDIT 2

Here's a version of the stylesheet which uses a key:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="attendances-by-class" match="/response/school1/class/attendance" use="class"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="first-attendances-of-each-class" select="
        /response/school1/class/attendance
          [generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('attendances-by-class', class)[1])]
      "/>
      <attendances>
        <xsl:for-each select="$first-attendances-of-each-class">
          <xsl:variable name="current-class-attendances" select="key('attendances-by-class', class)"/>
            <result class="{class}">
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$current-class-attendances/count != $current-class-attendances/count">
                <xsl:text>Check class roll</xsl:text>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>Perfect Attendance</xsl:text>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </result>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </attendances>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `attendances-by-class` key is an index of the `attendance` elements by the value of their `class` child element.

Firstly the key is used to obtain a list of the `attendance` elements which are the first to have a particular value in their `class` (this is what the `/response/school1/class/attendance[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('attendances-by-class', class)[1])]` expression achieves. The `generate-id()` function produces a unique string value for the `attendance` node, and that's compared with the corresponding value of the first of the `attendance` elements returned by the key. This is a bit more complicated than in my previous example which didn't use keys.

The `for-each` loop then iterates over that set of `attendance` elements. Inside the `for-each` loop the key is used again to retrieve the `attendance` records which belong to the same group. Here the key is a slight simplification over my previous example.

You asked for a help using `key` and so here's an answer. But I'd argue that the extra overhead of a key is barely worth it for a situation such as this: the number of records is so small (just 15) that the cost of searching use `preceding-sibling` is minimal, and actually comparable to the overhead for the XSLT processor of collating an index. It may save a few microseconds, but in the context of a piece of software that makes a web service call, that will be a tiny fraction of the total time.

Comment: The question is tagged as `xslt-1.0`  but `xsl:for-each-group` requires an XSLT 2.0 processor.

Comment: I have downvoted your edited answer because of its inefficient method of grouping.

Comment: For a small enough number of items it can be more efficient not to use a key. There are only three classes! So it's silly to reject my solution on that basis

Comment: Call me silly but I see absolutely no reason not to use Muenchian grouping. Always.

Comment: That's more than silliness, then; it's dogmatism. The point of Muench's method is to improve efficiency by using an index to select the members of a group from within a large nodeset. For a small nodeset, the overhead of building that index can be greater than the advantage of using the index.

Comment: I don't believe that is the case.

Comment: It certainly _can_ be the case. Whether it's true for this particular case is an empirical question. But in any case the performance difference will be microscopic, so it's not worth worrying about; it's more important to write something simple and get it right.